# Ajax with JSON is not working in IE 11

Tags: ajax, json, internet-explorer-11

The following ajax code works fine in Firefox,chrome,safari,IE9.But in IE 11,It is not working.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: req_type,
    url: req_url,
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    data: req_data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    processdata: true,
    success: function (data) {

        if (typeof callback === "undefined")
            alert("Callback method not found");
        else
            callback(data);
    },
    error: function (e)
    {
        console.log(e);
        alert("Error");
    }
```

req_type is POST and when I alert req_data,it is working fine but the JSON object is not received in Ajax page.Please help me.

Regards,

Rekha

Comment: I have debugged the  code and found that the issue was with $json=file_get_contents('php://input'); This is not working in IE 11.Can anybody knows the workaround for this.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for this by removing the following lines of code.

```
crossDomain: true,
cache: false,
processdata: true,
```

Now it is working fine.

Regards,
Rekha